# get rid of unwanted params in grails pagination

Tags: grails

I have a search webpage where user's can filter the search results by a person's ethnicity, as a checkbox group.  There are 12 'ethnicity' checkboxes.  The params get passed into g:paginate as the following, so that the user can page through the results and preserve what was checked in the ethnicity checkboxes:

```
<g:paginate controller="search" action="list" total="${resultCount}" params="${params}"/>
```

What gets output for the links includes a bunch of unnecessary data for each built URL:

```
<a href="/myapp/search/list?_ethnicity=&amp;_ethnicity=&amp;_ethnicity=&amp;_ethnicity=&amp;_ethnicity=&amp;_ethnicity=&amp;_ethnicity=&amp;_ethnicity=&amp;_ethnicity=&amp;_gender=&amp;_gender=&amp;_gender=&amp;accountType=2&amp;ethnicity=1&amp;ethnicity=5&amp;max=3&amp;offset=3" class="step">2</a>
```

I'd like the pagination link URLs to be output without all the extra _ethnicity variables that get passed back in the original search post:

```
<a href="/myapp/search/list?accountType=2&amp;ethnicity=1&amp;ethnicity=5&amp;max=3&amp;offset=3" class="step">2</a>
```

How can I get the params into the paginate tag without all the extra unnecessary fields?  Functionally it works, but the URLs for the paginate get requests are too long and look hideous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the previous user, this works to filter out the extra fields, though it is ugly.

```
params="${params.findAll { a ->
    if (!a.key.toString().startsWith("_")) {
        return a.value
    }
  }
}"
```

**EDIT:**

Actually a cleaner way is to put this in the controller:

```
params.keySet().asList().each { if (it.toString().startsWith("_")) params.remove(it) }
```

Then in the `g:paginate` you can stick with

```
params="${params}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..,.

```
<g:paginate controller="search" action="list" total="${resultCount}" params="${params.findAll { it.key == 'ethnicity' && it.value }}"/>
```

it gives you

```
<a href="/myapp/search/list?ethnicity=1&ethnicity=5" class="step">2</a>
```

---

One of the dirty way to achieve what you want is

```
<g:paginate controller="search" action="list" params="${
    params.findAll { a ->
        if (a.value instanceof Collection) {
            def c = a.value.findAll { b ->
                return b
            }
            if (c) {
                return c
            }
        } else {
            return a.value
        }
    }
}"/>
```

**EDIT:**

spock99 answer is much better than mine, one more way is

```
params="${params.findAll { !it.key.toString().startsWith("_") }}"
```